# Does .value("key", default) not work with empty json objects?

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I've run into a bit of a snag using the `value` function in the `nlohmann/json` library. I have an empty json object and I want to either initialize it or increment it if the nested keys are initialized. I've been trying to solve this problem using the value function, but I keep running into the error:

```
C++ exception with description "[json.exception.type_error.306] cannot use value() with null" thrown in the test body.
```

So, would this just not work?

```
nlohmann::json json;
std::string i = "1", j = "2", k = "3";
int old_value = json.value(i, nlohmann::json())
                    .value(j, nlohmann::json())
                    .value(k, 0);
json[i][j][k] = old_value + 1;
```

---

Edit: For those that want a better way to do this sort of thing, I've found a better way.

```
try {
    json[i][j][k].get_ref<nlohmann::json::number_integer_t &>()++;
} catch (nlohmann::json::type_error & ex) {
    json[i][j][k] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work for non-object json values, and the default constructor represents `null`, not `{}`.

From their [documentation](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_adcf8ca5079f5db993820bf50036bf45d.html#adcf8ca5079f5db993820bf50036bf45d) for `value()`:

> #### Exceptions
>
> - type_error.306  if the JSON value is not an object; in that case, using value() with a key makes no sense.

You'll have to initialize each one with `nlohmann::json(json::value_t::object)` or something else to initialize it to an empty *object*.